# How to get ClientBin location from OUTSIDE of silverlight Web project

Tags: c#, silverlight

What's the best way to get the system path to the ClientBin directory from outside of the silverlight .Web project.

I know that from within the .Web project, the following code will get me the physical path of the ClientBin directory:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(@"ClientBin\"));
```

How would I get the same DirectoryInfo object from another (non .Web) project within the Silverlight solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Uri sourceUri = new Uri(HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri,Application.Current.Host.

Source.ToString().IndexOf("ClientBin"))
```

Comment: Actually, IndexOf will return an int which is not allowed when creating an Uri